# Undefined variable in displaying values of index controller

Tags: laravel, routes

I am new to Laravel, I know I'm just missing out on something yet I cant seem to find it.

I am sending `compact('tabletinfo')` from my controller index to `home.blade.php` under `tablet` folder yet my `home.blade.php` can't seem to find `tabletinfo` variable.

Here's the code for index controller.

```
public function index()
{
    $tabletinfo = Tablets::all();
    return view ('tablet.home', compact('tabletinfo'));
}
```

CODE FOR `home.blade.php`

```
<tbody>
    @foreach ($tabletinfo as $tablet)
         <tr>
            <td>{{$tablet->owner_name}}</td>
            <td>{{$tablet->owner_address}}</td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewModal">View Details</button>
                <button class="btn btn-info edit" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal">Edit Details</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Delete</button> 
            </td>
        </tr>
     @endforeach
 </tbody>
```

> I guess my main problem is my view can't get the tabletinfo variable from my index controller.

Comment: Does it give you any error? could you paste the code instead of link to images

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ here's the error. 

`Undefined variable: tabletinfo (View: C:\Users\ZARI\TAB\resources\views\tablet\home.blade.php)`

Comment: it's strange in the image of your controller i can see `return view (tablets.home, ...)`. why the the error would say it is in `tablet\home.blade.php)`? those are different directories. Please, paste the code in your question

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ i edited my post, kindly look into it.

Comment: can you provide in which folder home.blade.php file exists ?

Comment: @RonakChauhan its under resources/views/tablet/home.blade.php

Comment: ok. all looks fine there. please post the route too.

Comment: Which error are you getting ?

Comment: you can see errorlog in file /storage/logs/laravel.log
Please post error

Comment: Which route do you mean ?@porloscerrosΨ

`Undefined variable: tabletinfo` in `tablet/home.blade.php` @RonakChauhan

Comment: @RonakChauhan `local.ERROR: Undefined variable: tabletinfo (View: C:\Users\ZARI\TAB\resources\views\tablet\home.blade.php)`

Comment: @kwestionable try to print variable in controller function like 
dd($tabletinfo );
and see what you are getting .

Comment: @kwestionable the route in `routes/web.php`. should be pointing your `Controller@index`  function. Somethig like `Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');`

Comment: I get collection of array @RonakChauhan

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ this is my route `Route::resource('tablet', 'TabletsController');
`

Comment: That means that you are getting value in that variable. the issue is you are not getting that in view.

Comment: @RonakChauhan yes, I am passing the `$tabletinfo` through `return view ('tablet.home', compact('tabletinfo'));` but the view cant get the variable. am i missing on something?

Answer (score 0):

there is a mistake. you write tablets instead of tablet

```php
return view('tablet.home',compact('tabletinfo));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this one ?

```
return view('tablet.home')->with('tabletinfo',$tabletinfo);
```

Or you can use this like

```
return view('tablet.home',compact['tabletinfo']);
```

Comment: hello, seems that I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: still nothing. this is getting frustrating. have you checked my `home.blade.php`? is there something wrong in the for loop?

Comment: Is that possible to post your entire home.blade.php file?

Comment: Which laravel version you are using ?

Comment: I can't post it. Characters are too long. Should I take a pic instead? I'm working on laravel 5.8

Comment: yes please.
Also it will be good if you post latest error from laravel.log file this will help us.

Comment: this is the laravel.log file `local.ERROR: Undefined variable: tabletinfo (View: C:\Users\ZARI\TAB\resources\views\tablet\home.blade.php) {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined variable: tabletinfo (View: C:\\Users\\ZARI\\TAB\
esources\\views\\tablet\\home.blade.php) at C:\\Users\\ZARI\\TAB\\storage\\framework\\views\\9001a7bb453c65272ca8169a6bafd89aa68e756a.php:26, ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined variable: tabletinfo at C:\\Users\\ZARI\\TAB\\storage\\framework\\views\\9001a7bb453c65272ca8169a6bafd89aa68e756a.php:26)
[stacktrace]`

Comment: Clear your cache by 
php artisan config:clear;
php artisan route:clear;
php artisan view:clear;

Comment: Oh.. man The issue is might be something else as all above mentioned method of passing variable to view is working well.

Comment: I might think so. Guess I just have to re-do all of it over again.

Comment: Install fresh laravel and try over there.

Comment: yes thank you for your answers :) I appreciate the help

Comment: I am disappointed that my answer could not help you. Nice to meet you.

Comment: No need to be disappointed, I was able to grasp what you're teaching me. Thanks!